# How to determine if a "multidimensional array view" with strides constitutes a continuous memory range?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Say we have this struct (class):

```
struct Array4DView {
    float* origin;
    std::array<int,4> dims, strides;
} v;
```

It represents a multi-dimensional array view in a way numpy does it (but that doesn't own memory pointed to by `v.origin`), whose dimension sizes are `v.dims` and strides are `v.strides`. So in order to access an element at (4,6,8,10), we'd need to do this:

`*(v.origin + v.strides[0]*4 + v.strides[1]*6 + v.strides[2]*8 + v.strides[3]*10)`.

Also let us define that view is continuous if and only if its elements occupy a single continuous memory block without gaps. Say,

`Array4DView view1 = {some_ptr, {2,3,4,5}, {5*4*3, 5*4, 5, 1}};`.

Then `view1` is continuous and has C-order (row-major order). The pros of a continuous view is that it can be correctly converted to a corresponding `std::span` with losing its dimension info but preserving its data. It then can be later converted to a byte buffer and written to a file (assuming no problems with byte ordering, IEEE float support etc).

This view could be constructed from a "true" multidimensional array by slicing it, like one could do in numpy. For example, in python+numpy code `pyview = pyarr[3:6, 2:8:2]`. In this case we can say that `pyview` is not continuous, or memory block that covers its elements has gaps in it that don't belong to any element of the view.

The question is what's the "best" algorithm to determine if a view is continuous?

---

Thanks to @MattTimmermans, this is the correct algorithm (as a member function):

```
bool is_continuous() const
{
    std::ptrdiff_t prod = 0; /* or std::size_t */
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        prod += (this->dims[i]-1) * std::abs(this->strides[i]);
    }

    return prod + 1 == this->num_elements();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to know this. It is more important that the underlying memory is contiguously allocated (e.g. all multidimensional data is put into one 1D array). Because as long as you step through that memory with predictable strides any normal CPU will be capable of prefetching what you are going to need. 
Also not C++23 has this new [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) which will do some of the offset/stride calculations for you at compile time.

Comment: Oh, I always had an impression that mdspan is only for contiguous mappings, but it indeed has `is_exhaustive()` which actually does what I need. Thanks! On the other hand, cppreference is incomplete on mdspan's `LayoutPolicy` template parameter, so it's hard to see what it really does and how it does that. :(

Comment: There is this great presentation from cppcon on mdspan : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCLmQEkPUw. I think it shows most of what it can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the farthest element from the origin -- the sum of all `strides[i] * (dims[i]-1)`.

If the storage is continuous, then it's 1 less than the number of required elements -- (product of all `dims[i]`) - 1